# How to stop Firefox from sharing Outlook login with Windows 10? (And adding that o365 e-mail address in Windows as a school account.)

Tags: windows-10, firefox, microsoft-outlook

Logging into Outlook e-mail (Firefox) for my university is adding that Microsoft account to Windows 10, under Word or School accounts (apparently). The university assigns students an o365.xxx.edu e-mail address. I never did a "Connect" with Windows 10 under settings with that e-mail address. I also have never "signed in" to Microsoft Word. (I have a retail / non-click-to-run Office installation, registered with a different e-mail address.) I have disconnected this e-mail address in Windows 10 settings.  How do I prevent this from happening again? How do I block Firefox from sharing my login with Windows 10? I have never enabled "Allow Windows single sign-on for Microsoft, work, and school accounts" in Firefox settings. I have never enabled Firefox sync. I never use Microsoft browsers, and Edge has been blocked by my firewall for a very long time. (So when Microsoft opens it for some reason, it has no internet access.)

Comment: >I also have never "signed in" to Microsoft Word. Do you mean that you have not active your Office(sign in your Office)?

Comment: No, Office is activated. There's a "sign in" on the top right of Microsoft Word, that I have never used.  I assume it gives you some connectivity features.

Comment: >I never did a "Connect" with Windows 10 under settings with that e-mail address. Please remove this account under Setting and check if the account will be connected again.